# Static file with Google App Engine and Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a problem.

I can't to access to any file from my static dir.

app.yaml:

```
application: campana-web-1
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /hello
  script: _go_app
- url: /.*
  static_dir: web
```

Structure:

```
campana-web-1:
  +-- src:
      +-- hello.go
  +-- web:
      +-- index.html
      +-- test.jpg
  +-- app.yaml
```

I use `goapp deploy .`

When I go to `http://website.com/hello` it work, but not when I replace hello by test.jpg or index.html I have

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

I miss something?

Thank you.

Comment: what about http://website.com/web/index.html?

Comment: I have a not found error

Comment: Possibly replace `- url: /.*` with `- url: /*.*`? I'm not sure if that will work, but it seems right.

Comment: I have tried your propose, but it does not work too.

Answer (score 1):

The *static_dir* feature maps directories to directories, but not files to directories as you're trying to do.

If you want to map a collection of files with globs (and no containing directory), then use a combination of *static_files* and *upload* instead.

For your case, it'd be:

```
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: web/\1
  upload: web/.*
```

But you can use *static_dir*, just don't use the glob part:

```
- url: /
  static_dir: web
```

This, too, should do the trick.

See the [Static Directory Handlers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers) and [Static File Patterns](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers) sections in the documentation again, and in particular, the section about static_dir that says: "Everything after the end of the matched url pattern is appended to *static_dir* to form the full path to the requested file."  That's why what you're doing doesn't work: the *static_dir* feature is much more limited in scope than what you're thinking.